# Create table with EBCDIC encoding in db2 i series

Tags: db2, iseries

I am working with AS400 system. I need to create tables with different encoding for validation task. I tested with

```
CREATE TABLE TESTSCH.EBCDIC_TBL (
COLUMN1 VARCHAR(100),
COLUMN2 INTEGER
) CCSID ebcdic;
```

However this is not working and throwing below error.

```
QL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword CCSID not expected
```

How to create a table with different encoding EBCDIC/ Unicode ASCII etc.

I am using Dbeaver to connect to AS400 system.

Comment: What version of Db2 i? Did you have a chance to look at the `CREATE TABLE` syntax in documentation?

Comment: Version 11. I followed this link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=data-creating-unicode-table

Comment: There's no IBM i version 11, and your link is for z/OS.

Comment: z/OS is not the same as IBM i (aka iSeries)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc's you linked to in your comment are for Db2 for z/OS, which is not the same as IBM i (aka iSeries).

Here's the Db2 for IBM i docs for the [CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-create-table).

And here's what your statement should look like assuming you want CCSID 37 US English

```
CREATE TABLE TESTSCH.EBCDIC_TBL (
COLUMN1 VARCHAR(100) ccsid 37,
COLUMN2 INTEGER
);
```

Other CCSID's can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-ccsid-values)

Also note that assuming a supported version of the OS, for Unicode UTF-16 you can use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR(xxx) ccsid 1200`

```
CREATE TABLE TESTSCH.UTF16_TBL (
COLUMN1 NVARCHAR(100),
COLUMN2 INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Appreciate it.